# return a column datafield from a database using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a  databse with the table registration ...Some of columns are Age,Username,Nationality and  Email

I have a method which should pick only the Column Nationality and return the items found in it,My method below does not show the error and have tested it with a radgrid but no values are being shown.Someone guide me on what the error might be in this method.Here is my method

```
public string GetNationalities(string nationals)
{
    var query = (from countries in db.Registrations
                 where countries.Nationalities == nationals 
                 select countries.Nationalities).FirstOrDefault();
    string returnValue = Convert.ToString(query);
    return returnValue;
}
```

I need to have only that column name Nationalities but its not picking any values.

Comment: try replacing `funds` with `countries`, however if so you will get back the `nationals`

Comment: Where does `funds` come from? Shouldn't this be `countries`, as King King suggested?

Comment: Sorry for the mixture,,,,i had another table too.Have changed but in my method when i use debugger,it shows null

Comment: have you checked that you have Nationalities in the database with the value of nationals ?

Comment: yeah,i have the   value in my databse